# Matching a Scala generic where type is unknown at compile time

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have two generic classes that inherit from a abstract parent that look like this:

```
abstract class Sketch[S]

class CompactSketch[S] extends Sketch[S]

class UpdatableSketch[U, S <: UpdatableSummary[U]] extends Sketch[S] {
    def compact: CompactSketch[S]
}
```

I have a function that returns the abstract type

```
def heapifySketch[S](bytes: Array[Byte], deserde: SummaryDeserializer[S]): Sketch[S]
```

I want to find out which of the two classes has been returned and modify if necessary

```
def ReadCompactSketch[U, S <: UpdatableSummary[U]](bytes: Array[Byte], deserde: SummaryDeserializer[S]): CompactSketch[S] = {
    heapifySketch(bytes, deserde) match {
        case s: CompactSketch[S] => s
        case u: UpdatableSketch[U, S] => u.compact
    }
}
```

Matching like this yields a warning about type erasure. I've looked into TypeTags, but I can't seem to find an example where the type isn't known until runtime. What is the proper way to verify that the heapifySketch has returned the correct generic type?

Comment: You can match like this `CompactSketch[_]` and use `asInstanceOf` on the return. In any case, your code is already unsafe.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's already unsafe"?

Comment: You are doing a class check which breaks parametricity, which means you have a failed abstraction. Also, you are treating your checks as it was done a closed ADT but it is done on an open OOP interface.

Comment: [This code seems to work without a warning](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zZtHivOFTUSxWhBdTaVNBg) once you fix `extends Sketch[S]` etc. I do agree that this is bad design, but it *is* safe (at least in terms of the generic types). I don't know why it compiles as `extends Sketch`... is it a raw types compat thing?

Comment: sorry, that's a typo. I've elided some of the class details

Comment: so are you saying that a better design would be to have an individual function for each unique case? I'm locked into the class configuration as its part of a library.

Comment: the heapifySketch function is part of an outside library, too

Comment: edited. see above

Comment: So as @HTNW said, this seems to work: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/D6PugntrSPCkxzODiFgUWQ/10

Comment: I know that it works, but the example is still trying to match a generic type, which results in a type erasure warning. I'm trying to figure out the most proper way to write this function, but maybe there isn't a right way.

Comment: @kellanburket well you can do [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/D6PugntrSPCkxzODiFgUWQ/12). And hope nothing crashes in runtime.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. Thank you for your help. Perhaps I'll just try to write individual functions for each unique case.